# 'And' 'Or' Query in ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, .net, linq, elasticsearch

```
public class User 
{
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
  public bool Active { get; set; }
}

client.Index(new User { Email ="test@test.te" });
```

Query in Linq C# for example :

```
rep.Where(user=>user.Email=="test@test.te" &&  (user.Age>18 || user.Active== true));
```

How to make this query for Elasticsearch (I mean same query in Elasticsearch)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of :

- `range` filter for the `age` field ([reference](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-filter.html))
- `term` filter for the `email` and `active` fields ([reference](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-filter.html#query-dsl-term-filter))
- a `bool` filter with `should` clauses (equivalent to OR) to combine the `age` and `active` filters ([reference](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html))
- another `bool` filter to combine the previous one with the `email` filter in `must` clause (equivalent to AND)
- A `filtered` query to be able to use filters defined above.

It may be useful for you to know the [differences between query and filters](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_queries_and_filters.html#_queries_and_filters).

You should end with something like this :

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "email": "test@test.te"
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "age": {
                        "gt": 18
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "active": "true"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note:

for this query to work, the email field must be `not_analyzed` as the term filter looks for the **exact** same value.